# Looker P&L building table

Tags: looker-studio, looker

I'm trying to build a table set in the form of a P&L in Looker studio. To build a table inside Looker you need to use the Pivot form, and it's not meeting my requirements (ex. I want a line 5 to be the sum of line 1, 2, 3, 4, then I want line 7 to be the difference between line 5 and 6...). So, how can I do to have this flexibility avoiding the only option of a pivot table in looker studio?

Thnx for the help

I tried to add a table on Looker studio but it's impossible to customize meeting my requirements

Answer (score 0):

Its a good question, Looker Studio is probably not the best tool to make a P&L as it is a data visualization tool and not a Business information tool, a locked down Google sheets is probably a better option for you, but there is a way.

You can not use **A** pivot table because the row logic does not work in the way you want it to as it will break down the vectors in the field that you have selected by the measures.

You can use pivot table**S**, a different one for each row in the pivot table you are trying to create(headers hidden), each one with its own measure doing the calculations that you are after.

This will give the illusion of a P&L with out it being one.